# Would somebody explain for a beginner what the line with FOR command does?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new on batch script writing, and I have to change some line in batch code.

I need to understand what the command line below means:

```
for /f %%i in ('logicals -t file_location') do set DIR=%%i
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets the result of command `logicals -t file_location` and sets the first part (parts are delimited with space) of the result to the `DIR` variable. [Here's more info](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

have on mind that `logicals` command is not native command in windows , nut is an external utility.

Answer (score 0):

That is Windows Batch for assign output of program to variable.

For more information see [Reading the output of a command into a batch file variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out all about batch commands by typing for /? in the command prompt.

One thing to consider is that the for command works slightly differently in a batch file compared to just running the command on the command line because you have to double up the %% characters.

For this question what this command is doing is running the command 
`'logicals -t file_location'` and then each line of output from that command (which I assume is a path specifier) is then passed as an argument to the `dir` command.

Answer (score 0):

`for /f`: Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.

Syntax:

```
    FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command 

    FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command
```

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html